# Proposal for Community ad 2013

Tags: discussion

Are we fine with the twitter ad? I mean, Twitter is so 2011? Perhaps we need to go with the flow and make a Google+ logo, whether we do something with it or not.

- Al (alias Eddie)
- ChrisF
- Barry
- Sathya
- Hydra
- Philippe
- Jacob Jan (myself)

and many more are present on G+.

All in favor? Perhaps we can change the current name of the Google+ page we have, along the way too...

Comment: Who is capable of making such a logo in the first place? I'm not.

Comment: Once you decide the name for the Google+ I will throw something together

Comment: I am quite in favor of the original name, can't think of any alternatives that are better right now anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say go ahead with the Google+ ad, I would be more than happy to help out with updating the Google+ page.

If we do use the Twitter ad, we need to also decide on whether we should use the @StackWebApps or @nothinginstall for others to follow. Nonetheless I am also on Twitter (@hydrizwiki) to help out if needed. :)

Answer (score 2):

The twitter ad is a demo.

> This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Nothing prevents you from adding a new ad to that post, such as a G+ ad.

As for the Google+ page, I just need the email address of whoever wants control and you can change it to however you please as long as you abide by SE Trademark and Naming.

Comment: You can add my name to it: see my profile.